# Using CMS_sign() with CMS_CADES flag including certificate chain for CAdES compliance. Do I have to use CMS_PARTIAL flag?

Tags: openssl, cryptography

Will the following generate message signature compliant to CAdES?

The API doc for CMS_sign() seems indicate in order to use SHA256 for message digest, I need to use the flag "CMS_PARTIAL". Also the [openssl's CAdES patch](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/7893) seems to imply the CMS_PARTIAL and manually call  "CMS_add1_signing_cert_v2()" followed by "CMS_final()" as well. But I was hoping adding CMS_CADES flag to CMS_sign() could have been sufficient. Hence the ask.

My questions are for any OPENSSL C API experts:

1. Will the following use SHA1 to generate message digest?
2. Will the following generate cryptographic message syntax compliant to CAdES standards ([RFC-5126](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5126))?
3. If SHA256 is the required method to generate message digest, do I have to use CMS_PARTIAL?

   CMS_ContentInfo *CMS_sign(signcert, EVP_PKEY *pkey, STACK_OF(X509)*intermediate_certs, BIO *data, CMS_DETACHED | CMS_CADES);

Answer (score 0):

I tested my own code on Ubuntu using OPENSSL 3.0.0-Alpha4. CMS_sign() by defaults uses SHA2256. So the answer to 3 is no: no need to use CMS_PARTIAL flag just to pick up SHA256 as the MD.